Can antimatter create antigravity?
CERN's scientists have discovered that antimatter does not create antigravity, they have dropped , or observed an antimatter particle with the help of a magnetic field and after making this discovery NASA's warp drive scientists say that to create a warp drive They do not need anti gravity. Is it true that antigravity cannot be created from antimatter, how did they discover this and is there mathematical proof of it?


Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/139545/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/83307/2451 and links therein.

antimatter still has a positive mass-energy density.

The mathematical proof: mass is a property of the field, not an observable operator like charge or what else, so charge conjugation (i.e. flip between matter & antimatter, bar parity inversion and time reversal) doesn’t change it.

@controlgroup charge is also a property of the field, it just happens that it comes in two flavors unlike mass.

The linked duplicates are 10 year old descriptions of the first experiment done at CERN. It showed that antihydrogen falls down. Error bars were large. It was consistent with the same acceleration as usual. But the actual measured value was 3/4g. Better measurements were needed. The photo above is from the CERN press release where better measurements were done. ALPHA experiment at CERN observes the influence of gravity on antimatter

Error bars are still large, but the new results is acceleration is the same as usual to 20%. Here is a PBS Space Time video that tells why people why people might have expected a different answer and why they would care. Does Antimatter Create Anti-Gravity?
